# Installed Android Studio Canary: where can I get hardware profile for Google Pixel 6 and Pixel 6 Pro

Tags: android-studio

Where can I get Google Pixel 6 / 6 PRO hardware profiles for Android Studio (Canary, freshly installed)

Comment: Do you find any answer for that?

Comment: Was wondering the same thing.

Comment: i am also looking for same for this